# How to make a custom texteditor work with the undo and redo shortcuts after modifying the DOM?

Tags: javascript, events

I am building a small custom editor using the `contenteditable` attribute on a div.

By default, when the user pastes HTML content, the HTML is inserted in to the `contenteditable` div, which I do not want.

To solve this issue, I used a custom paste handler like this question suggests:

[Stop pasting html style in a contenteditable div only paste the plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980235/stop-pasting-html-style-in-a-contenteditable-div-only-paste-the-plain-text)

```js
editor.addEventListener("paste", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

  document.execCommand("insertText", false, text.replaceAll("\n", "<div><br></div>"));
})
```

---

So far so good. Because the [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand) is deprecated, I used a replacement, which is to basically use ranges to insert the text (stripped of HTML) by hand.

[execCommand() is now obsolete, what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581285/execcommand-is-now-obsolete-whats-the-alternative)

[replace selected text in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997659/replace-selected-text-in-contenteditable-div)

```js
editor.addEventListener("paste", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

  const selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.deleteFromDocument();

  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(text));
  range.collapse();
});
```

This worked well until I noticed, that the undo and redo commands were not working anymore after pasting something. This is because of the DOM modifications done in the custom paste event, which is a deal breaker.

---

In search of a solution I found the following question:

[Allowing contenteditable to undo after dom modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217539/allowing-contenteditable-to-undo-after-dom-modification)

The first answer there suggests to use the **`execCommand`, which is deprecated, so it's not a good solution**.

The second answer suggests building a custom undo redo stack to handle all these events by hand. So I opted for the second solution.

---

I build a custom undo redo handler using a simple array to store the versions. For that I used the [`beforeinput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event) event to listen for the undo and redo events.

```js
editor.addEventListener("beforeinput", (e) => {
  if (e.inputType === "historyUndo") {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("undo");
  };

  if (e.inputType === "historyRedo") {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("redo");
  };
});
```

This works very well for undos, however, due to me preventing the default, the browsers undo/redo stack is never in a state to redo, so the `beforeinput` listener is never fired when pressing `cmd + z` or `ctrl + z` on windows.

I've also tried this using the `input` event with the same result.

I've searched for other solutions to handle the undo/redo events using JavaScript, but **building a custom handler using `keydown` is no option** here, because every OS uses different shortcuts, especially mobile devices!

### Question

Now, There's multiple possible solutions to solve my problem, so any of them that works is very welcome.

Is there a way to handle the paste event by hand and insert the pasted plaintext into the document while keeping the undo/redo functionality or implementing a replacement to such functionality by hand?

### Example

Try to paste something and then undo, it wont work.

```js
const editor = document.getElementById("editor");

editor.addEventListener("paste", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData("text/plain").replaceAll("\n", "<div><br></div>");
        
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.deleteFromDocument();

  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(text));
  range.collapse();
});
```

```css
#editor {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

### Edit

Modifying the `ClipboardEvent` does not work because it's read only. Dispatching a new event also does not work because the event would be untrusted, so the browser does not paste the content.

```js
const event = new ClipboardEvent("paste", {
  clipboardData: new DataTransfer(),
});

event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", "blah");

editor.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: To prevent your question from being closed for being not focused, I suggest you combine your four questions into one big idea.

Comment: Also, you wouldn't need `e.preventDefault()` if the default doesn't do anything, right?

Comment: After you prevent the default. Instead of using execCommand. Create a custom paste event with the text you want and dispatch it to the element. That way it believes that a paste was done and uses the original stack/method.

Comment: @John Creating a new `ClipboardEvent` does not work because the new event is untrusted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645587/how-to-create-a-paste-event-after-preventdefault

Comment: @swift-lynx duplicate/clone the entire editor script. Edit the out the trust check.

Comment: @Rojo The default does nothing if the text field is empty. If the content has been edited, I want to handle the undo myself, so I have to prevent the default action by the browser.

Comment: @swift-lynx You don't ***need*** to call `preventDefault()` if you are manipulating the event. The only time you ***need*** it for form submits, where the code won't run since the page reloads. Try running it without `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Rojo I tried removing the `e.preventDefault()` form the `paste` event and from the `beforeinput` event. Now when pasting, the data is inserted twice, the first time the escaped one and the second time the original html one. The undo still only works for the original html paste, not for the one inserted using ranges. I'm also not manipulating any events because the properties I'd need to edit are readonly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ommitting `preventDefault` from the undo/redo

Comment: @Rojo I tried that too, doesn't work either

Comment: Could you elaborate on doesn't work?

Comment: @Rojo The undo works with my custom undo/redo solution, but the `beforeinput` event still doesn't fire when trying to redo, because the browsers undo/redo stack is empty

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem and solved it using the approach discussed in [this writeup](https://dev.to/chromiumdev/-native-undo--redo-for-the-web-3fl3), with his original code [here](https://github.com/samthor/undoer). It's quite a clever hack. In the end, his approach still uses `execCommand`, but it is a very narrow and hidden use of `execCommand` just to push an integer index onto the native undo stack so that your "undo data" can be tracked on a separate stack. It also has the benefit of being able to intersperse normal undo operations (like reverting typed-in input) with the ones you push on to the separate undo stack.

I had to modify his undoer constructor to use an 'input' element rather than a contentEditable 'div'. And because I'm already listening for 'input' in my own contentEditable 'div', I needed to `stopImmediatePropagation` on the hidden input.

```
constructor(callback, zero=null) {
  this._duringUpdate = false;
  this._stack = [zero];
  
  // Using an input element rather than contentEditable div because parent is already a
  // contentEditable div
  this._ctrl = document.createElement('input');
  this._ctrl.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
  this._ctrl.setAttribute('id', 'hiddenInput');
  this._ctrl.style.opacity = 0;
  this._ctrl.style.position = 'fixed';
  this._ctrl.style.top = '-1000px';
  this._ctrl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  this._ctrl.tabIndex = -1;
  
  this._ctrl.textContent = '0';
  this._ctrl.style.visibility = 'hidden';  // hide element while not used
  
  this._ctrl.addEventListener('focus', (ev) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => void this._ctrl.blur(), 1);
  });
  this._ctrl.addEventListener('input', (ev) => {
    ev.stopImmediatePropagation();  // We don't want this event to be seen by the parent
    if (!this._duringUpdate) {
        callback(this.data);
        this._ctrl.textContent = this._depth - 1;
    } else {
        this._ctrl.textContent = ev.data;
    }
    const s = window.getSelection();
    if (s.containsNode(this._ctrl, true)) {
        s.removeAllRanges();
    }
  });
}
```

I create the undoer and a way to capture the undoerData I'm using for paste and other operations that need access to the range when the operation took place. To use it for paste, I listen for the paste event in my own contentEditable div (call it `editor` below).

```
const undoer = new Undoer(_undoOperation, null);

const _undoerData = function(operation, data) {
  const undoData = {
    operation: operation,
    range: _rangeProxy(), // <- Capture document.currentSelection() as a range
    data: data
  }
  return undoData;
};

editor.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pastedText = undefined;
  if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
      pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  }
  const undoerData = _undoerData('pasteText', pastedText);
  undoer.push(undoerData, editor);
  _doOperation(undoerData);
});
```

Then the `_doOperation` and `_undoOperation` switch on the operation and have the information in undoerData to take the proper action:

```
const _doOperation = function(undoerData) {
  switch (undoerData.operation) {
    case 'pasteText':
      let pastedText = undoerData.data;
      let range = undoerData.range;
      // Do whatever is needed to paste the pastedText at the location
      // identified in range
      break;
    default:
      // Throw an error or do something reasonable
  };
};

const _undoOperation = function(undoerData) {
    switch (undoerData.operation) {
      case 'pasteText':
        let pastedText = undoerData.data;
        let range = undoerData.range;
        // Do whatever is needed to remove the pastedText at the location
        // identified in range
        break;
      default:
        // Throw an error or do something reasonable
    };
};
```

With this scheme and the pasteText operation implemented, you can now copy text, paste - type - delete text - type - reposition cursor - paste, and then undo 6 times with the _undoOperation being invoked on the 1st and 6th undo while the others just work like they're supposed to.

Comment: One day maybe we will have an undo API exposed properly and can avoid all this. This looks like an early draft... https://rniwa.github.io/undo-api/